# Accessing Outlook ost file

Tags: c#, outlook

I have seen the difference between pst and ost files and currently working on accessing the outlook pst file through the following code given below. 
Is there any way to use the same code for accessing ost file? Can someone refer me to this?

```
private DataTable GetInboxItems()
{
    DataTable inboxTable;
    //try
    //{
    filter = "[ReceivedTime] >= '" + dtpStartDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy 12:00 AM")   + "' and [ReceivedTime] <= '" + dtpEndDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy  11:59 PM") + "'";
    Outlook.Application outlookApp = GetApplicationObject();
    Outlook.Folder root = outlookApp.Session.DefaultStore.GetRootFolder() as  Outlook.Folder;
    EnumerateFolders(root);
    //string filter = "[ReceivedTime] > '" + dtpStartDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")  + "'";

    //inbox
    Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder =  outlookApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    inboxTable = CreateTable();
    int count = 0;


    if (inboxFolder.Items.Count > 0)
    {

        var restrictedItems = inboxFolder.Items.Restrict(filter);
        restrictedItems.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", true); //descending
        //foreach (var item in inboxFolder.Items)
        foreach (var item in restrictedItems)
        {
            var mail = item as Outlook.MailItem;
            if (mail != null)
            {
                //try
                //{
                DataRow row = inboxTable.NewRow();
                //row["sn"] = (++count).ToString();
                row["sn"] = mail.EntryID + " " + mail.ReceivedByEntryID;
                row["MailType"] = "Inbox";
                row["SenderName"] = mail.SenderName;
                row["SenderEmail"] = mail.SenderEmailAddress;
                row["ReceivedDate"] = mail.ReceivedTime;
                row["Subject"] = mail.Subject;
                row["Body"] = mail.Body != null ? (mail.Body.Length > 25 ?  mail.Body.Substring(0, 25) : mail.Body) : null;
                //row["Body"] = mail.Body != null ? mail.Body : "";
                row["MailSize"] = mail.Size.ToString();
                string attachments = null;
                if (mail.Attachments.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var attachment in mail.Attachments)
                    {
                        if (((Outlook.Attachment)attachment) != null)
                            //attachments = ((Outlook.Attachment)attachment).FileName +  " " + ((Outlook.Attachment)attachment).Size.ToString() + ", ";
                            attachments += (((Outlook.Attachment)attachment).Size / 1024).ToString() + " KB, ";
                    }
                }


                row["AttachmentCount"] = mail.Attachments.Count;
                if (attachments != null)
                    row["AttachmentSize"] = attachments.Substring(0, attachments.Length - 2);

                inboxTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            //catch (Exception ex)
            //{

            //    return null;
            //}

        }
    }

    return inboxTable;
}
```

Comment: This code works with Store object, it doesn't care if the store is PST, OST or online exchange without offline file. Did you have problems with this code? Maybe it requires credentials...

Comment: Thanks Arthur...How can i access OST file? could you please demonstrate with a code example at what point credentials are required? And what benefit does this OST file provides over PST file?

Comment: OST is created when using cached mode in Exchange account type, you can't control it. PST is used to store mail data without server account or using other type of accounts like IMAP. The code you have in your question will read OST file if the default store is of Exchange account. Did you tried it? Did you had problems?

Comment: I didn't try it as i am confused about how to point to the OST file of the Exchange account. How to pass the credentials etc.?

Comment: you don't need to point to the OST file. the code accesses a running instance of the Outlook app. It will prompt for credentials. Just try the complete code as I posted as a solution below.

Comment: Aspose libraries are used to achieve this. Reading this sample could help https://github.com/aspose-email/Aspose.Email-for-.NET/blob/master/Examples/CSharp/Outlook/PST/ConvertingOSTToPST.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to educate yourself on what OST/PST is as the access to them is not much different, both are [Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb609139%28v=office.14%29.aspx) objects so they have the same interface.

Try this sources for a start and experiment yourself as it's the best way to understand how stuff works.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_Storage_Table

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb609139(v=office.14).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184648(v=office.14).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208208(v=office.12).aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rambab/OutlookIntegration10282006032802AM/OutlookIntegration.aspx

Comment: ***HOW-TO*** manages `OST` files using C# for convert to _PST_ or simply reads emails from **OST** ?

Answer (score 4):

After I figured out how to actually build the code provided by OP, I found it very useful to get started on Outlook, so I would like to share the completed code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;//List
using System.Linq;//Array
//using System.Text;
//using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;//Process
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;//Marshal
using System.Data;//DataTable
using System.Reflection;//Missing
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;//.OST files, needs Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll

//TO DO: If you use the Microsoft Outlook 11.0 Object Library, uncomment the following line.
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace WatchOutlookMails
{
    class StoreFormat
    {
        public DataTable GetInboxItems(DateTime dtpStartDate, DateTime dtpEndDate)
        {
            DataTable inboxTable;
            string filter = string.Format("[ReceivedTime] >= '{0:dd/MM/yyyy 12:00 AM}' and [ReceivedTime] <= '{1:dd/MM/yyyy 11:59 PM}'", dtpStartDate, dtpEndDate);
            Outlook.Application outlookApp = GetApplicationObject();
#if false//only needed if you want to select another folder
            Outlook.Folder root = outlookApp.Session.DefaultStore.GetRootFolder() as Outlook.Folder;
            EnumerateFolders(root);
#endif
            //inbox
            Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = outlookApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            inboxTable = CreateTable();
            if (inboxFolder.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                Items restrictedItems = inboxFolder.Items.Restrict(filter);
                const bool SortDescending = true;
                restrictedItems.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", SortDescending);
                foreach (var item in restrictedItems)//item is a "COM Object" (?)
                {
                    MailItem mail = item as Outlook.MailItem;
                    if (mail != null)
                    {
                        //try
                        //{
                        DataRow row = inboxTable.NewRow();
                        //row["sn"] = (++count).ToString();
                        row["sn"] = mail.EntryID + " " + mail.ReceivedByEntryID;
                        row["MailType"] = "Inbox";
                        row["SenderName"] = mail.SenderName;
                        row["SenderEmail"] = mail.SenderEmailAddress;
                        row["ReceivedDate"] = mail.ReceivedTime;
                        row["Subject"] = mail.Subject;
                        row["Body"] = mail.Body != null ? (mail.Body.Length > 25 ? mail.Body.Substring(0, 25) : mail.Body) : null;
                        //row["Body"] = mail.Body != null ? mail.Body : "";
                        row["MailSize"] = mail.Size.ToString();
                        int AttachmentSize = 0;
                        foreach (Outlook.Attachment attachment in mail.Attachments)
                        {
                            if (attachment != null)
                                AttachmentSize += attachment.Size;
                        }
                        row["AttachmentCount"] = mail.Attachments.Count;
                        row["AttachmentSize"] = AttachmentSize;
                        inboxTable.Rows.Add(row);
                        //catch (Exception ex)
                        //{
                        //    break;
                        //}
                    }
                }
            }
            return inboxTable;
        }

        private DataTable CreateTable()
        {
            DataTable T = new DataTable();
            T.Columns.Add("sn", typeof(string));
            T.Columns.Add("MailType", typeof(string));
            T.Columns.Add("SenderName", typeof(string));
            T.Columns.Add("SenderEmail", typeof(string));
            T.Columns.Add("ReceivedDate", typeof(string));
            T.Columns.Add("Subject", typeof(string));
            T.Columns.Add("Body", typeof(string));
            T.Columns.Add("MailSize", typeof(int));
            T.Columns.Add("AttachmentCount", typeof(int));
            T.Columns.Add("AttachmentSize", typeof(int));
            return T;
        }

        private void EnumerateFoldersInDefaultStore()
        {
            Outlook.Application outlookApp = GetApplicationObject();
            Outlook.Folder root = outlookApp.Session.DefaultStore.GetRootFolder() as Outlook.Folder;
            EnumerateFolders(root);
            return;
        }

        private void EnumerateFolders(Outlook.Folder folder)
        {
            Outlook.Folders childFolders = folder.Folders;
            if (childFolders.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Outlook.Folder childFolder in childFolders)
                {
                    // Write the folder path.
                    //Debug.WriteLine(childFolder.FolderPath);
                    // Call EnumerateFolders using childFolder.
                    // Uses recursion to enumerate Outlook subfolders.
                    EnumerateFolders(childFolder);
                }
            }
            return;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// obtain an Application object that represents an active instance of Microsoft Outlook, 
        /// if there is one running on the local computer, or to create a new instance of Outlook, 
        /// log on to the default profile, and return that instance of Outlook
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private Outlook.Application GetApplicationObject()
        {
            // source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462097.aspx
            Outlook.Application application = null;

            // Check whether there is an Outlook process running.
            if (Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count() > 0)
            {

                // If so, use the GetActiveObject method to obtain the process and cast it to an Application object.
                application = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
            }
            else
            {

                // If not, create a new instance of Outlook and log on to the default profile.
                application = new Outlook.Application();
                Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
                nameSpace.Logon("", "", Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                nameSpace = null;
            }

            // Return the Outlook Application object.
            return application;
        }
    }//end class
}//end ns
```

To fill in the missing pieces, I borrowed from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310259, for EnumerateFolders: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184607.aspx