# Accessing Contacts From .OST File Office 2010/2013

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

Let me preface by saying that I don't work with office COM object's and generally try to avoid  it like the plague.  I also know this question has been beat to death with regard to accessing .pst files, however after an hour of googling I've yet to find to much regarding .ost.

I'm trying to update a method in an existing application, the app was accessing a .pst file and retrieving a list of contact names and emails to be used in an autofill implementation.  We recently changed from a direct IMAP to Host Email server to Microsoft Exchange which changes to from .pst to .ost file

This is the method:

```
    var arrName = new List<string>();
    var arrEmail = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        var outlookApplication = new ApplicationClass();
        NameSpace mapiNamespace = outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        MAPIFolder contacts = mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);

         for (int i = 1; i < contacts.Items.Count + 1; i++)
         {
             var contact = (ContactItem) contacts.Items[i];
             arrName.Add(contact.FullName);
             arrEmail.Add(contact.Email1Address);
         }
            Global.ConName = arrName.ToArray();
          Global.ConEmail = arrEmail.ToArray();
        }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        //Error Logging
    }
```

When called throws the following Error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to 
interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ContactItem'. 
This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM 
component for the interface with IID '{00063021-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' 
failed due to the following error: 
No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

at OPUSfin.LoginMain.GetEmailContactsFromOutlook() in PATH:line 81
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I can modify this to work with the Exchange implementation ?

Thankyou

Ref: [Accessing Outlook ost file Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372082/accessing-outlook-ost-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have DistListItem objects besides ContactItem that your code expects.

Use the "as" operator to check if you really have a ContactItem object.
You might also want to cache the Items collection before entering the loop:

```
Items items = contacts.Items;
for (int i = 1; i <= items.Count; i++)
{
    ContactItem contact = items[i] as ContactItem;
    if (contact !=null)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```