# Shadow copy of .ost file

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, shadow-copy

I use .ost file and try to create shadow copy for 2 files:

- \?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy22\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\test@mail.ru.ost
- \?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy22\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\test.txt

But when I call:

```
File.Exists(shadowFilePath)
```

I get **false** for *test@mail.ru.ost* and I get **true** for *test.txt* file.
How can I create shadow copy of .ost file when I use outlook ?

Comment: have you tried getting and or checking for all .ost file extensions in a particular directory..? can you show you you are assigning the particular `shadowFilePath` in your code..?

Comment: Outlook uses 1 e-mail only, so I have only one .ost file. If I open Outlook, I can't copy .ost file to another directory and file in shadow copy doesn't exists (I think shadow copy can't copy .ost file too)

Comment: try reading the links posted here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372082/accessing-outlook-ost-file

Comment: Thank you !!!!!!!